# run object on 45 degree angle + sprite kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to figure out how to move an object on 45 degree angle on screen using Sprite Kit downwards? Below is the function I am using but it take consideration of x and y co ordinates while moving, however I want object to move on 45 degree.

Sample Code:

```
CGFloat distanceToMove = frameHeight; 
float durationTime = 0.025 * distanceToMove; 
_moveObjectStraight = [SKAction moveByX:0
y:-frameHeight duration:durationTime];
_moveObjectRight = [SKAction moveByX:frameWidth y:-frameHeight duration:durationTime];
```

Answer (score -1):

Moving at a 45 degree angle is just using the same values for x & y. What sort of problem are you running into?

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for quick reply, as you can see from _moveObjectRight method object is moving right and downwards , however i want to move object downwards exactly on 45 degree downwards.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Clearly, in your example, "frameWidth" and "frameHeight" aren't the same value. Make the X and y movements the same magnitude, and the sprite will move on a 45 degree angle. This is basic trigonometry.

Comment: Thanks , that worked, actually "frameWidth" and "frameHeight" were not same , but as you said i made it same it worked as i desired, Thanks allot.